# PHP get user temp directory

Tags: php, temp

The server which xampp runs is 'PC-1'. So when I try with

```
getenv('temp')
```

and

```
var_dump(getenv('temp'),$_ENV);
```

and

```
sys_get_temp_dir();
```

all of them return **C:\Users\PC-*1*\AppData\Local\Temp** which is fine.
But when I run from PC-2 I want to get that system's temp dir as

**C:\Users\PC-*2*\AppData\Local\Temp** where the above function shows PC-1's temp dir.

Comment: You are trying to retrieve the *client's* temp dir??

Comment: @PeeHaa: Yes. You are right.

Comment: php runs _on the server side_. so 1. it does not have any knowledge about the client side setup and 2. even if it would, security concerns would never allow you to see such information. Even if you _could_ find out, what would you do with that information?

Comment: Not possible form PHP. Also why would anyone ever need this?

Comment: Actually I write the contents of a java result page into a text file (which can not be done by java) in temp directory then it would be read by an intranet application which will wait for the text file's existence and the text file contents will be read by that application before delete it. Anyhow thank you @PeeHaa and arkascha for let me know about the client tempdir retrieval function's unavailability.

Comment: Can't you just use a shared directory for this?

Comment: We are not allowed to use shared directory for this process. It is only for authorized people which the persons doing tests should not be allowed.